# Why is my JavaScript object property inaccessible, when it IS, in fact, defined?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, destructuring

Here is the object. It is a second-level object in the data tree:

```
user: {
  userId: 3,
  username: 'aragorn',
},
```

My React component is destructuring its parent object and making it available to the entire component. When I render the **full user object** using this code:

```
<p className="small">
  {`Submitted by ${JSON.stringify(user)}`}
</p>
```

I get a complete stringified object with all of *user's* properties:

[image: Complete object renders in string form]

When I try to access only the 'username' property from the 'user' object:

```
<p className="small">
  {`Submitted by ${JSON.stringify(user.username)}`}
</p>
```

I get this error:

[image: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined]

Have you ever faced this weird issue before?

For further study, here is the full data object. This is coming from a mock data object being exported from a neighboring file in the same app. No network requests to a backend or anything, so there shouldn't be any async stuff going on here (I may be wrong):

```
{
title: "The Hefalump's Tale",
page: '32',
line: '1',
author: 'Joni E. Driskill',
genre: 'Sci-fi',
type: 'Motivational',
content: 'The grass is greener on the other side, unless, in actuality and reality, it is not. I guess in that case, you can just give up on anything nice in life.',
claps: 23,
id: 4,
user: {
  userId: 3,
  username: 'aragorn',
},
comments: [
  {
    commentId: 0,
    quoteId: 0,
    content: 'Comment content',
    userId: 'userId',
    claps: 2,
    date: 2,
  },
  {
    commentId: 1,
    quoteId: 1,
    content: 'Comment content',
    userId: 'userId',
    claps: 4,
    date: 1,
  },
  {
    commentId: 2,
    quoteId: 2,
    content: 'Comment content',
    userId: 'userId',
    claps: 12,
    date: 0,
  },
],
```

},

And HERE is my React component, called 'Meta,' bringing in the 'quote' object as a prop. The primary line in question is toward the bottom, but feel free to look at my props destructuring, too, if you like:

```
import React from 'react';
import Clap from '../mechanics/Clap';
import Report from '../mechanics/Report';

const Meta = ({
  quote: {
    content,
    title,
    author,
    page,
    line,
    genre,
    type,
    claps,
    id,
    user,
  },
}) => (
  <div className="discussion-meta mb2">
    <h1>&ldquo;{content}&rdquo;</h1>
    <hr />
    <div className="columns is-spaced-around pb3 text-align-left">
      <div className="column">
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <p>
          <small>by {author}</small>
        </p>
        {page ?
          <p>
            <small>page {page}{line ? `, line ${line}` : ''}</small>
          </p>
          : null
        }
      </div>
      <div className="column text-align-right">
        <p>
          <span className="tag-purple small">{genre}</span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <span className="tag-green small">{type}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="columns">
      <div className="column">
        <p className="small">
          {`Submitted by ${JSON.stringify(user.username)}`}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="columns">
      <div className="column">
        <Clap claps={claps} />
      </div>
      <div className="column">
        <Report id={id} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Meta;
```

I've recreated in CodeSandbox, and it works! WTF!
https://codesandbox.io/s/4q9nlywl1x

Comment: Are the props sent down to `Meta` the result of a network request? It might be that `user` is not set for the first render, but then it gets set when the request is complete and it is re-rendered.

Comment: It is not. It's simply an object exported from another file in the same app.

Comment: Alright. Do you think you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)? It would be easier to help you that way.

Comment: Try ```{user ? <p className="small">
  {`Submitted by ${JSON.stringify(user.username)}`}
</p> : null```, which will prove @Tholle 's point

Comment: Done: https://codesandbox.io/s/4q9nlywl1x

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan That worked! Why would grabbing an export from a neighboring file be async though?

Comment: JSON.stringify convert an Object to string. JSON.stringify(user) -> user is an object
but user.username is a string ? Why do you want to convert a string to string?

Comment: Just something I forgot to change when switching from accessing the object to accessing the string property. Shouldn't affect anything though...

Comment: You should consider using `$(user.username}` instead.

Comment: This is what we have now, and it works:
```{user ?
          <p className="small">
            {`Submitted by ${user.username}`}
          </p>
          : null
        }
```

Comment: Well if your sandbox example is identical in setup to your working one, then it should work, otherwise, there is something with your dev environment setup, with regards to webpack or babel. I am not sure, but this indeed looks pretty strange. Can you put out a working github repo?